# POST a hidden input + multiple options PHP

Tags: php

Hi there I'm quite new to PHP

I have this problem:

I would like to POST a multiple choice + a hidden field from a form:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['nickname']))
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
    $teamsCount = ceil(mysql_num_rows($result)/2);
    for ($i=1; $i<=$teamsCount; $i++)
    {
        // TEST: echo $i . " TeamsCount er: " . $teamsCount. "<br>"; 
?>
Team <? echo $i; ?> 
<form name="addTeam" action="buildTeams.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" value="<?php $i; ?>" />
    <select name="teams[]" multiple="multiple" size="<?php echo mysql_num_rows($result); ?>">
    <?php 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            $id=$row["ID"];
            $nick=$row["Nick"];
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($nick); ?></option>
<?php   
        } 
?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Make them teams!!" />
</form>
<?php 
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This seems correct, the data will be available in the $_POST array of buildTeams.php when the form is submitted. Could you specify what is not working?

Comment: your question is too vague. elaborate it more.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, anyway if you place an hidden textbox and a multiple option inside a form, POSTing that form sends all fields contained in it...

Comment: Sorry my code looks very very messy..

My question is:

How do i POST the hidden field with the value $i together with the multiple choice?


The variable $i should be the 'TeamID' and the multiple choice should be the team members.

I hope you understand

Comment: Rafael Almeida thanks for the fast respons:

if i print_r($_POST[teams]);

I get only the data from the multi choice, and not the hidden field (variable $i)

Comment: If you take a look to source code of generated web page, is that hidden field present with the correct value? And more: di print_r($_POST) and see all the variables contained in it

Comment: This is what i print:

    if (isset($_POST["teams"]) && isset($_SESSION['nickname']))
    {
    print_r($_POST["teams"]);
    }

Comment: Hmm..

Marco the hidden fields value=""

And not the value i expected

CORRECTED - This is because I changed it before from <?echo $i?> to <?$i ?> but it still doesn't work

Comment: But you gotta check $_POST['hiddenField'] to obtanin hidden value... am I wrong?

Comment: Well try printing the name of the hidden field: `print($_POST['hiddenField']);` - if you want to see what has been submitted in full, try `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: @Marco wrong bracket type and missing quotes around the key name...

Comment: @DaveRandom: thanks Dave, my answer was too quick... I missed something, thanks again. But `print_r($_POST)` was in my previsou post :) Ah ah ah :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an error in this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" value="<?php $i ?>" />
```

It should be

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" value="<?php echo $i ?>" />
```

Edit:

Put the team id in the select name. Example:

```
<select name="teams[<?=$i?>][]">
```

And in PHP do:

```
foreach ($_POST['teams'] as $team_id => $choices)
```

Comment: Or the shorter version value="<?=$i?>"

Comment: Ok then, try the following: instead of posting the ID as a hidden value, just use it in the <select> name. For example: <select name="team[<?=$i?>][]">. And in php do something like: foreach ($_POST['team'] as $team_id => $choices) ...... That way you can easily post multiple teams with multiple members in them.

Comment: Well it would work, but then the user has to choose the multiple option of TeamID to post the TeamID aswell as the userIDs..

This is what i want:

Say we have 10 users, then I can make 5 teams (2 in each)

I then would like to show 5 different multiple choices (forms) where the admins/users can choose which users to which teamID

I know it's kind of weird explained :S

If you know a better method please tell :)

Comment: Uhm I'm not intirely sure how to do that.. - 

In other words does it do a huge difference?

Comment: Yes it does a significant difference :) In your original example the hiddenField will be overridden by the last iteration of the for(). To properly post team ids with the chosen members of each team you need to put the $i in the select name. Just use my code example and do a print_r($_POST['teams']) to see what I mean.

Comment: I'm not sure where to put the foreach? `<select name="teams[<?=$i?>][]" multiple="multiple" size="<?php echo mysql_num_rows($result);?>">` This is what I did now.

And the post: `print_r($_POST['teams']);` -> Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 17 ) )

Comment: The foreach needs to go in buildTeams.php where you save the selected teams and members.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST["teams"]) && isset($_SESSION['nickname']))
{
 foreach ($_POST['teams'] as $team_id => $choices){echo $team_id . " " . $choices;};` returns: "1 Array"  - why is that ?

Comment: Because $choices contains a list of selected members for the team $team_id.

Comment: Ooohh I see :) - thanks for your help I know what to do now.

Thanks all of you guys

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check `$_POST['hiddenField']` to obtain hidden value

Comment: Thanks Marco I think I know how to fix the problem..

I've changed the 'hiddenField':

Array ( [TeamID] => 1 [teams] => Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 17 [2] => 18 ) ) 

and this happens when I print $_POST

I'm not sure why I can't combine it in one array, but it doesn't matter now.. I can just get the TeamID..

And thank you guys it really helped :)